# how to override email html file in magento2

Tags: magento2, template

I want to change following text in checkout page

```
You can create an account after checkout.
```

Actually this line is coming from following file.

app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html

Can you any one give approach to override?

Comment: Where do you need to override file: in theme or custom module?

Comment: in custom module.also if email is not existed only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create [Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                                                    Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email <!--  <- you can change component here -->
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="description" xsi:type="string"
                                                                          translate="true"><!--  <- you can change text here -->
                                                                        We'll send your order
                                                                        confirmation here or you custom text.
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: getting blank page after adding this xml.

Comment: in log: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []